# Etymology and usage of idiom "d'accord, Hector!"

Tags: usage, étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques, prénoms

According to the dictionary, there is the following idiom in French: "d'accord, Hector!" which means something like "OK, let's assume". I have some questions about it:

1. Regarding etymology, what Hector gives us this idiom? Or what's its origin?
2. Is it really used widely in modern French?
3. Any good examples of usage?

Comment: Isn't it just jocular rhyming slang? I seem to recall hearing "d'accord, victor" in the same use...

Comment: @Circeus Exactly, like *Fonce Alphonse.! *Allons-y Alonso* (I'm a Doctor Who fan)

Comment: They're not variations as such, they're popular phrases built on the same patern, rhyming slang on a name. I'm sure there's never been real characters behind the names. They're not interchangeable and are not used in the same circumstances.

Comment: Well as I just starded to learn french I didn't noticed that there is a rhyme in the phrase actually... It was not obvious to me at the first glance... it takes some practice to align spelling with pronunciation... :)

Comment: Je suis tombé par terre…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez:... c'est la faute à Voltaire...

Comment: Le nez dans le ruisseau…

Comment: … c'est la faute à Rousseau. (Dernière strophe de la [chanson de Gavroche](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavroche#Biographie_du_personnage), célébrissime en France.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of rhyming slang on a name is rather popular but I don't really know to what extent. The name is chosen for its rhyming capacity with the action described in the first part of the sentence.  And of course each one is said on a particular occasion.

- **D'accord Hector !** You say that to signify you approve what someone has just suggested to do. The English equivalent would be *okey-dokey* (exact equivalent as far as rhyming slang is concerned except in English it doesn't rhyme with a name).
- **Fonce Alphonse !** To encourage someone to go ahead with whatever they want to do.
- **Ça roule Raoul !** To signify you're going to do whatever's been discussed.
- **Tu parles, Charles !** You say it when you don't really believe what you've been told.
- **À la tienne, Étienne !** when you toast someone.
- **À l'aise, Blaise !** to signify you can do something easily.

Comment: Ne pas oublier le poétique "**Dans l'cul, Lulu !**" ...

Comment: These expressions look odd abd this oddity is used to achieve funny effects. There is maybe some occurences in “Zazie dans le métro.” Occasionally some of them enjoy a temporary popularity in some friend circle. I also used _Aboule, Raoul!_, _Cool, Raoul!_, _Peinard, Bernard!_, _Zen, Ben!_, _Tranquillou, Billou!._ Do not mistake with fakes _Tranquille le chat_ or _En voiture Simone!._

Comment: You have the same in English, for example in old rock'n'roll  like "See you later, Aligator".